# JFIF response decoding

Tags: javascript, postman, base64, decoding, jfif

from the beginning I'd like to apologise for my first post:)
I struggling 3 days with decoding JFIF response and try visualize it in postman tab.

Does anyone know how to decode response in the "air" and visualize it in postman TAB:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ3Ny.png)
When I download and save it as jpg, then open it everything working fine.
I'd like to skip this step , my collection has much TestCases and opening every to look inside the saved file  will be too efortless and without sense according with automation everything.
Kesonex.

I've read everything and checked many codes till today, I installed node.js and newman. What else can I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No code for that till today. I can't find any solution to decode from unicode(JFIF) which occurs in response to base64 and then I can display a picture.